# If $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is compact, then $M \subset \mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is exponentially tight?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, large-deviation-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space, $\mathcal B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\mathcal M_1(E)$ the set of probability measures on $(E,\mathcal B)$. I'm interested in when and why the following implication holds.

> If $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is compact, then $M \subset \mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is [exponentially tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures#Exponential_tightness).

Is this always true? For what reason?

A script I'm studying says something along the lines of "we do not need to worry about exponential tightness (of $M \subset \mathcal{M}_1(E)$) because $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is compact". Here, $E$ is a bounded, open, connected subset of $\mathbb R^d$ with a smooth boundary and $M$ is the sequence of local times of a Brownian motion. And I see that $\mathcal{M}_1(E)$ is compact in this case, but not why exponential tightness follows.

It sounds to me like there's a simple argument that makes this statement true in a general setting, but I couldn't come up with a proof. So I wonder: why and when is it true?

Comment: There are several things I don't understand in your question. 1) Why do you say $\mathcal M_1$ is compact? It is not: let $\{x_n,n\ge 1\}$ be a sequence of points converging towards $\partial E$. Then the sequence of delta measures $\delta_{x_n}$ does not have a limit point. 2) what is $M$ precisely? Where does the "sequence" come from?

Comment: However, if the set $\mathcal M_1$ were compact (say, if $E$ is compact), then indeed the exponential tightness is trivial: just take $K_\varepsilon = \mathcal M_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! 1) Sorry, I should have specified that $\mathcal M_1(E)$ is endowed with the topology induced by weak convergence. In this case, pointwise convergence is actually equivalent to convergence of Dirac measures. 2) Well, I'd say the "sequence" comes from the ordering of the index set, but I might be using the term incorrectly. I mean the measures $\mu_t = \int_0^t \delta_{B_s} \mathrm ds$ where $B=(B_s)$ is a Brownian motion. 3) I don't get $K_\epsilon = \mathcal M_1$. $\mathcal M_1$ is not a subset of $E$!

Comment: 1) This is exactly my point. In my example, the sequence $\{x_n,n\ge 1\}$ converges to a point outside $E$, so the corresponding sequence of delta-measures does not have a weak limit point in $\mathcal M_1(E)$. 2) I thought that you have measures on $\mathcal M_1(E)$. But in fact it seems that you have measures on $E$. So I guess that $\mu_t (A) = \int_0^t \mathbf 1_A(B_s) ds$, $A\in \mathcal B$, is this correct?

Comment: 1) I had gotten confused there.. You are, of course, right that the limit measure is not in $\mathcal M_1(E)$ I'm rather puzzled now about the statement in the script. 2) $\mu_t$ is indeed what I meant.

Comment: By the way, you have measures on $\mathcal M_1(E)$, not on $E$: these are distributions of $\mu_t$. Another interesting question is how $B_t$ is defined on $E$. Maybe, $E\subset \mathbb{R}$? Is the script available somewhere? Looking inside might help to answer these questions.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you are right, since the $\mu_t$ are random variables which take values in $\mathcal M_1(E)$, so their distribution is on $\mathcal M_1(E)$ as well. The script is available here (p. 61), but it's in German: https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/koenig/www/GA.pdf